# Spark SparkPi example

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

In the SparkPi example that comes with the distribution of Spark, is the `reduce` on the RDD, executed in parallel (each slice calculates its total), or not?

```
val count: Int = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 until n, slices).map { i =>
  val x = random * 2 - 1
  val y = random * 2 - 1
  if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
}.reduce(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

By default, this example will operate on 2 slices. As a result, your collection will be split into 2 parts. Then Spark will execute the `map` transformation and `reduce` action on each partition in parallel. Finally, Spark will merge the individual results into the final value.

You can observe 2 tasks in the console output if the example is executed using the default config.

Comment: Cool! So no need to be "smart" and send a closure to compute sub-totals on each executor instead of using ```reduce```. I like it, just have to trust Spark :-)